# Resizing the height of an appended iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, resize, append

I am creating a page that allows people to upload a file which can then be edited directly inside the browser. What I have created so far is the upload form which upon submitting loads the content into an iframe by appending that iframe to a div.

Upon submitting the form the following jquery runs:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.email-body').append('<iframe id=\"emailframe\" scrolling=\"no\" src=\"email/index.html\" width=\"800\" name=\"myFrame\"></iframe>');
    $('.emailUploadArea').fadeOut();
    $('.email-body').fadeIn();
}, 50);
```

This part works just fine; the upload form disappears and the iframe appears with the email inside.

The issue is that the iframe that appears is only 150px in height and I need the iframe to expand to display the entire file inside. I was using this jquery when the iframe was static instead of being appended.

```
function resizeIframe() {
    var iframe_content = $("#emailframe").contents().find('body');
    $("#emailframe").css({
        height: iframe_content.outerHeight(true)
    });
    iframe_content.resize(function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        $("#emailframe").css({
            height: elem.outerHeight(true)
        });
    });
}
```

But this no longer works, I assume because jquery can't find the iframes id as it's not really there.

Could someone show me how to do this so that my appended iframe will resize itself to show the entire file.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than appending a string containing a definition of an iframe, try creating one dynamically first and saving a reference to it:

```
var myIframe = $('<iframe id="myFrame" name="myFrame">');
myIframe.appendTo('body');
```

That way, you'll have a reference to it that will allow you to modify whatever attributes you'd like!

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2010/02/dynamically-create-iframe-with-jquery.html